# app icon is greyed out when installing app on iOS(both 8.3 and 9.3.2) but the app installs correctly

Tags: ios

We have a problem of the app icon being greyed out while installing on the phone from iTunes or appStore.after installing the app icon becomes the one we expect.Happens on both iOS 8.3 and 9.3.2 . Anyone knows how can we have the desired icon also while installing the app? We specified all the AppIcons asked in the Images.xcassets files , while also tried this method : https://makeappicon.com/ios9icon but still we have the same problem. Thanks in advance

Edit: here you have the image as well !https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMlA5.jpg

Comment: Can you show the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think it's because your icon contains transparents zones. Is that right ?

An iOS icon can't be composed of transparent, otherwise it will be grayed.

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear enough in the description.it's not greyed out,actually the icon is not displayed....so the default grey icon is displayed.you can see it in the image I attached